# Variable Input not inserting into SQLite3

Tags: python, sqlite

i'm a bit of an amateur IT Professional who has been getting to grips with Python and Django. This query is just for Python and SQLite3.

So I have the following code, which is meant to take an input from the user, and then pass it to a function I have created.

```
from dbadd import inputdetails
import sqlite3
conn = sqlite3.connect('torndata.db')
c = conn.cursor()


print('Enter Name')
u_name = str(input())
print('Enter Age')
u_age = int(input())
print('Enter Gender')
u_gender = str(input())


inputdetails(u_name, u_age, u_gender)
conn.close()
```

And this is the function it is calling:

```
import  sqlite3
conn  =  sqlite3 . connect ( 'torndata.db' )
cursor  =  conn.cursor ()


def inputdetails(u_name,u_age,u_gender):
  cursor.execute("""
INSERT INTO userdata(name, age, gender)
VALUES (?,?,?)
""", (u_name, u_age, u_gender))
conn.commit()
```

I get no errors when it runs, but when I run the following, it shows no data has been moved to the table I have specified.

```
c.execute("SELECT * FROM userdata")
print(c.fetchall())
conn.commit()
conn.close()
```

The database is already created within SQLite3 and the table has been set up, I can query it directly.

Answer (score 0):

Bad indent. The commit statement is not part of the function.